# CorelDRAW X3 оптимизация

Tags: corel-draw

Не совсем программерский, конечно, вопрос, но я схожу с ума. По долгу своей работы, использую корел, работаю с вектором. Беру логотип, обрабатываю его векторно, т.е. там точку поставить, здесь удлинить линию...по мелочи, потом экспортирую в расширение .plt... дальше неважно. Корел постоянно открыт, кроме него на компе загружен firefox, Skype, Avast, totalcomander и в зависимости от настроения VisualStudio 2010 или eclipse...
Eclipse нашёл как ускорить, VS2010 не особо, но меня устраивают лаги его... Зато Корел... как он тормозит... не могу нормально alt+tab, когда начальство входит... да и в процессе тоже, загрузка логотипа и т.д. Кто-нибудь может посоветовать дельное что-нибудь по этому вопросу?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Corel - требовательная к памяти программа. Если при переключении окон система тормозит, возможно, что памяти не хватает и время тратится на работу с файлом подкачки. Можно проверить в системном мониторе (Ctrl+Shift+Esc) так ли это. Если так, то надо докупать память.

Еще можно поиграть с настройками памяти Corel. Зайти в Tools > Options -> Workspace/Memory.

- Выставить флажок Enable Compression (чтобы сжимать данные и реже обращаться к диску).
- Нарастить Memory Usage, например, до 75% (чтобы большая часть памяти была за Corel).
- Указать два диска для файлов подкачки Swap Disks.

И кроме того, зайти на вкладку Workspace/General.

- Сократить значение Undo levels, чтобы откаты занимали в памяти меньшее место.

Comment: Спасибо) Чуть глубже вздохнул...